# Passing Databricks Notebook Path in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I always get this error when i try dynamic content - `@string(activity('Lookup1').output)`

Actually when I tried to run the ADF pipeline using the location it is always giving the error and I am not able to figure it out why it is giving this error. Also, I tried checking the escape characters but also still I am not able to pass the notebook path. I tried searching google but didn't find the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Also, to be clear. I am passing using a sql table where the first row is the path in that table which is the path location of particular notebook.

Comment: Could you please add the complete error message or screenshot of the error message?